# Closing or minimizing the cmd window

Tags: c++, windows, cmd

How could I close a cmd window when I start windows api written in c++, I'm still learning the code but am making some amateur programs such as 2048 game, that's my latest one but it's irritating to have both program window and cmd open at the same time even though cmd closes when the main window closes.

So I was wondering if there is a way to either minimize it or (even better) close/not open it.

Comment: If you create a Windows application rather than a console application, you won't even *see* the console window. What compiler/build system are you using? Visual Studio? That'll help us give more detailed instructions.

Comment: Yeah, VS13, I never tried making a win application, only console since I'm still learning advanced c++. I did try a few times but didn't really work out for regular c++ programs...so if I just pick win api and copy over my code it won't open the cmd window ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The only advantage of a console application is that you don't have to create your own window to display output. The C++ language is no more complex, in fact it's exactly the same regardless of which type of app you chose. And since it sounds like you're already creating your own main window, you don't need a console application. The standard Windows application will work fine.

Comment: Wow thanks, I really didn't imagine it's as simple as that...I don't have issues creating my own window, still learning some stuff like bitmaps and such, I thought it's way more complicated then just changing the project type :))

Answer (score 1):

I know others have given you a better solution in comments.  However I thought I would post the answer to your original question in case anyone else finds this.

Add this include file: `#include <Windows.h>`

Then run this command at the start of your program:

```
int main() {

FreeConsole(); // Removes the console window

...
}
```

Comment: I like this solution because it addresses the problem without addressing IDE specific details like "project type" or whatever it is called in particular products.

Comment: @Brandin It also makes it very convenient to disable/enable the console for debugging purposes.  Just strap a #ifdef DEBUG in front of the command (and even Windows.h if you don't need it for other reasons) and you're good to go.

Comment: @Brandin It's actually a linker option and something you *need* to know about if you're writing Windows apps. It just so happens that the exact switch you use is different for different build tools. For MinGW, you pass `-mwindows` instead of `-mconsole`. For Microsoft's CL.exe, you specify `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` switch instead of `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE`. kkuryllo's is ***not*** a "better" solution. If you wanted a console for debugging purposes, you'd want to manage it manually, invoking it with `AllocConsole`. But I don't know why you'd want that, there are great debugging features built in.